# OpenTelemetry not picking up Env Variable for Endpoint

Tags: go, open-telemetry

I am using go and `go.opentelemetry.io/otel` for OpenTelemetry Tracing.

The code for initializing tracer is

```
func NewTracerProvider(ctx context.Context, service string) (*sdktrace.TracerProvider, error) {
    exp, err := otlptrace.New(ctx, NewClient())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    res, err := resource.New(ctx,
        resource.WithAttributes(
            // the service name used to display traces in backends
            semconv.ServiceNameKey.String(service),
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    tp := sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
        sdktrace.WithBatcher(exp),
        sdktrace.WithSampler(sdktrace.AlwaysSample()),
        sdktrace.WithResource(res),
    )

    otel.SetErrorHandler(&errorHandler{})
    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)

    propagator := propagation.NewCompositeTextMapPropagator(propagation.Baggage{}, propagation.TraceContext{})
    otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagator)

    tracer = tp.Tracer(service)

    return tp, nil
}
```

And when I print the logs when the connection is refused.

```
2023-08-11 17:54:06 
message="2023/08/11 15:54:06 This is OTLP Variables2 - db_run ENABLE_TRACING: true and OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT: http://tempo.service.consul:65322 and ctx value %!s(bool=true)"
2023-08-11 17:53:59 
message="runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598 (0x46fd41)"
2023-08-11 17:53:59 
message="go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk@v1.16.0/trace/batch_span_processor.go:128 (0xad6c45)"
2023-08-11 17:53:59 
message="go.opentelemetry.io/otel@v1.16.0/handler.go:48 (0xad7c98)"
2023-08-11 17:53:59 
message="go.opentelemetry.io/otel@v1.16.0/internal/global/handler.go:87 (0xad7c99)"
2023-08-11 17:53:59 
message="2023/08/11 15:53:59 open telemetry error: internal.wrappedExportError traces export: context deadline exceeded: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4317: connect: connection refused\""
2023-08-11 17:53:56 
message="2023/08/11 15:53:56 \"GET http://127.0.0.1:65314/status HTTP/1.1\" from 127.0.0.1:57950 - 200 16B in 28.755268ms"
```

Log is printing this.

```
log.Printf("This is OTLP Variables2 - %s ENABLE_TRACING: %v and OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT: %s", moduleName, viper.GetBool("ENABLE_TRACING"), viper.GetString("OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT"))
```

Why would it not pick up the env variable? On local it is picking up, but not when I deploy to my instance. Should I pick up the URL and initialize oltptrace with that? Not sure whats happening here.

Tried setting up the env variable but seems to not work. Verified if the env variable was set properly. Checked with ChatGPT it cannot say it absolutely either.

Comment: Well, while you do not tell that, I take you mean your `NewTracerProvider` calls some bits of the OpenTelemetry SDK which are expected to use certain env. variables for configuring itself, right? If so, then why you're using `viper`, which is a complex library which is able to pull configuration data from multiple sources at once, to check what you think are env. variables? If you want to specifically check env. vars, then do _exactly_ that and use the functions from the `os` standard package.